# Deployment failed for running windows phone8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I wrote first app using VS2012, Its giving error that is "Error 1 Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.
" 
but I did not attach any phone; I just want to run it on emulator. I am unable to select emulator from Visual Studio Device option as Its only showing me "Device" option. please help me how emulator options will come in Device options

Answer (score 1):

After you install the SDK bundle. XDE emulators begin to setup themselves immediately consuming a large ram from your rig. It might have happened that you restarted your pc/laptop while the XDE was setting up.

So i would suggest you to Unistall and Reinstall again the SDK package with Update 3 to enjoy no problems. Also please note that you are running windows 8.1 pro or Enterprise/Embedded Industry pro edition.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have the Windows 8.
2. You should have a Hyper-V compatible computer.
3. You should enable and configure the Hyper-V. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx
4. If you use a laptop, development on the emulator will be a hell.

Comment: "If you use a laptop, development on the emulator will be a hell". There's no justification for this. My experience on a laptop has been absolutely fine.

Comment: @spender, if you use a non-English locale, you can't run the Hyper-V. If you run the Hyper-V, you can't use the sleep or hibernation. So your laptop isn't laptop anymore, it's just a computer with a battery. For some laptops there are no updates for the BIOS. So, they technically support the Hyper-V, but not in the reality. But maybe something was changed from the August.

Comment: Hmm. I did re-roll my laptop with server 2012 which might have helped. Putting svr2012 on a laptop really was a PITA! Since I turned on Hyper-V, I haven't noticed any of the bad effects you describe. Hibernate and sleep "seem" fine (although I only did this a few days ago...). Laptop is hardly new (over 2 years old), but with latest BIOS etc. Maybe I was just lucky.

Comment: @spender, I don't suppose that installing a Windows Server for non-server development is a good practice. From any point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Try grant all permission level to all user for your virtual machines in this path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images

Answer (score 0):

Only restart the device or the emulator and the deployment will success

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Hyper-V installed using **Control Panel|Programs & Features|Turn Windows Features On/Off**.

If you installed Hyper-V AFTER Visual Studio 2013, you will need to repair Windows Phone x.x Emulators in **Control Panel|Programs & Features**.

Reboot.

The Emulator should appear in the Visual Studio Run/F5 button.

It will take several minutes to start the emulator on the first try. It will appear to hang. Wait at least 10min. You can use Hyper-V Manager to connect to the emulator directly and view progress.